# Ant Ivy: Producing text report of the runtime jars

Tags: ant, ivy

Normally, when we download jars from Ivy, we set `pattern` to include the version number of the jar.

```
<ivy:retrieve
    pattern="${lib.dir}/[conf]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"
    log="${ivy.log}"/>
```

However, for this one project, we can't do that. Jars have to be downloaded without version ID on them:

```
<ivy:retrieve
    pattern="${lib.dir}/[conf]/[artifact].[ext]"/>
```

This app is installed by *overwriting* what is already there. If a revision of a particular jar gets changed from one release to the next, we would end up with both the older jar and the newer version of that jar, and we would not know which version was being used. Removing the revision information makes it easy to make sure that older jars are replaced with the newer version.

However, the developer would still like a simple report on what versions of the jars were downloaded and put into the built war, so how can I generate such a report. I was looking at `ivy:report` but it doesn't produce a text report. There's a [`<ivy:artifactreport/>`](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/artifactreport.html) task, but that also produces an XML report and not a text report.

I could parse this report using Perl or Python, but I'd rather not use an executable as part of the build process. Otherwise, when a developer does a build, they'll have to make sure these external programs are correctly installed and configured.

Is there an easy way to produce a plain text report?

Comment: The XML produced by artifactreport could be transformed into text using the ANT xslt task.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor Thanks. I'll have to look into that. I guess it's time for me to learn some xslt. I was trying the xmlproperties task, but that ended up being a bit of a disaster. It ended up putting all of the jar names in one property, all of the revisions in another property, all of the organizations in another property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uses the ANT [xslt](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/style.html) task to generate a CSV formatted text file

## Example

```
├── build
│   └── ivy
│       ├── com.myspotontheweb-demo-compile.html
│       ├── com.myspotontheweb-demo-runtime.html
│       ├── com.myspotontheweb-demo-test.html
│       ├── ivy-report.css
│       ├── report.txt
│       └── report.xml
├── build.xml
├── ivy.xml
└── report.xsl
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="resolve" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">

    <target name="resolve" description="Use ivy to resolve dependencies">
        <ivy:resolve/>

        <!-- Reports -->
        <ivy:report todir='build/ivy' graph='false' xml='false'/>

        <ivy:artifactreport tofile="build/ivy/report.xml"/>
        <xslt style="report.xsl" in="build/ivy/report.xml" out="build/ivy/report.txt"/>

    </target>

</project>
```

### report.xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="modules/module/artifact"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="artifact">
    <xsl:value-of select="../@organisation"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="../@name"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="../@rev"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="origin-location"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="cache-location"/>
    <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### report.txt

```
org.slf4j,slf4j-api,1.7.5,http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.5/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar,/home/mark/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/jars/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
org.slf4j,slf4j-log4j12,1.7.5,http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.5/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar,/home/mark/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar
log4j,log4j,1.2.17,http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.jar,/home/mark/.ivy2/cache/log4j/log4j/bundles/log4j-1.2.17.jar
junit,junit,4.11,http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/junit/junit/4.11/junit-4.11.jar,/home/mark/.ivy2/cache/junit/junit/jars/junit-4.11.jar
org.hamcrest,hamcrest-core,1.3,http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar,/home/mark/.ivy2/cache/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-core/jars/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
```