# How to convert XML to CSV

Tags: xml, ssis, xslt-1.0

I have XSLT script which convert my source XML to Other XML format.
Now I am Looking to convert that target format as Tab delimited file
using current XSLTLogic.

CUrrent XSLT as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns1="http://www.ofdaxml.org/schema" targetNamespace="http://www.ofdaxml.org/schema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
<xs:element name="PurchaseOrder">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="OrderLineDetails" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="VendorRef" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xs:element name="LineItemNumber" type="xs:unsignedByte" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xs:element name="SpecItemNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xs:element name="SpecItemDesc" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xs:element name="ITMOptionCode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xs:element name="ITMOptionSeq" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xs:element name="ITMOptionDesc" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xs:element name="ITMOptionCodeDescOld" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xs:element name="ITMOptionCodeDesc" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" ="4000"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Please can any one tell me what are the changes I have to make in above file to get CSV file with same out put which is getting now me

Comment: That is an XML schema file, not an XSLT script....

Comment: This is the only example I have on SO of generating CSV using an XSLT stylesheet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20550146/ant-ivy-producing-text-report-of-the-runtime-jars/20575723#20575723